# Pass a lambda as a variable to a .Select()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to pass a lambda to my .Select() method depending on a condition.

I set my lambda up like this:

```
Func<Monthly, int?> f = x => x.CLDD;
```

I then set up my .Select() like this:

```
IQueryable query =
 db.Monthlies
 .GroupBy(o => o.Date.Value.Year)
 .Select(
   o => new {
     Year = o.Key,
     MaxDate = o.Max(x => x.Date),
     Data = o.Sum(f)
   }
 )
 .Where(o => o.Year != currentYear)
 .OrderBy(o => o.Year);
```

The code compiles and runs fine but the query does not send back any results. When I debug and watch query I see it says:

```
+ base {"Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025."}
System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Note if instead I do:

```
Expression<Func<Monthly, int?>> f = x => x.CLDD;
```

Then o.Sum(f) errors saying:

```
Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 
'System.Linq.IGrouping<int,MyWeb.Models.Monthly>' to
System.Linq.IQueryable<MyWeb.Models.Monthly>'
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Equiso: please post your answer as an actual answer so that mbird can accept it. Otherwise, the question looks like it hasn't been answered yet, wasting other people's time and preventing people from later finding this answer when they need it. (mbird: if Equiso does not eventually post an actual answer, note that you can do it yourself, and accept it...again, to ensure that this question is correctly shown as answered).

Comment: [Related meta post for answers in comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, Entity Framework needs an `Expression` to work not `Func`, but the `Sum` extension method that receives an `Expression` works only with `IQueryable`.

Now inside `Select` you are getting an `IGrouping` from `GroupBy` which does not implement `IQueryable` only `IEnumerable`.

So you just need to cast it to get the right extension method:

```
Data = o.AsQueryable().Sum(f)
```